# Calculate the minimum value of a database in python with the min sql query

Tags: python, sql

I have a database: my column-name is `waarde` and my tablename is `tblWaarden`.

He doesn't print the minimum value but

```
SELECT MIN (waarde) FROM tblWaarden
```

Is there anyone that can help me?

```
def CalculateMin(dbFilename):
     connection = sqlite3.connect(dbFilename)
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     sqlQuery = "SELECT MIN (waarde) FROM tblWaarden"

     sqlCommand = sqlQuery.format()
     cursor.execute(sqlCommand)
     print(sqlQuery)
     connection.commit()
     connection.close()
```

Comment: You need to use `cursor.fetchone`, `cursor.fetchall`, or iterate over the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
 print(sqlQuery.fetchone())
```

This prints the result as a list with one element.

or:

```
 print(sqlQuery.fetchone()[0])
```

This prints the one item in the value.